# How do I query multiple documents in Flutter Firebase where id isEqualTo currentUser uid? - Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, provider

I have a view screen where I want to display all customers. The customers are displayed in a list view format.

In my CustomerNotifier class, I set the customer id to be the same as the currentUser id, so automatically, it should only display customers created by current logged in user.

```
  getCustomers(CustomerNotifier customerNotifier) async {
    String userId = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;

    print('Current logged in user uid is: $userId');

    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('customers')
        .where("id", isEqualTo: userId)
        .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();

    List<Customer> _customerList = [];

    snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
      Customer customer = Customer.fromMap(document.data);
      _customerList.add(customer);
    });

    customerNotifier.customerList = _customerList;
  }    

  Future createOrUpdateCustomer(Customer customer, bool isUpdating) async {
    CollectionReference customerRef =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('customer');
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String userId = user.uid;
    print('Current logged in user uid is: $userId');

    if (isUpdating) {
      customer.updatedAt = Timestamp.now();
      await customerRef.document(userId).updateData(customer.toMap());
      print('updated customer with id: ${customer.id}');
    } else {
      customer.createdAt = Timestamp.now();

      DocumentReference documentReference = await customerRef.document(userId);
      // add(customer.toMap());

      customer.id = documentReference.documentID;

      print('created customer successfully with id: ${customer.id}');

      await documentReference.setData(customer.toMap(), merge: true);
      addCustomer(customer);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I can successfully write to the database. However, reading all customer documents and displaying the customers created by currentUser (where document id == currentUser uid) doesn't show in my customer ListView.

I've been at this for days and can't seem to figure out why. I'd appreciate some help in what I might be doing wrong/overlooking.

Thanks.

***Please note my flutter project dependency versions are as below:***

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  provider: ^4.3.1
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.0
```

Comment: Is the `id` in the `where` referring to the documentID or a field in the document named id?

Comment: Yes it is. I've edited the main question to include a screenshot of my firebase. it's named id.

Comment: I also added my customer model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collection is 'customer' not 'customers' change your query to:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('customer')
    .where("id", isEqualTo: userId)
    .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
    .getDocuments();
```

Comment: Good catch! changed to customer and now. It only shows recently created customer. Not all of it created by the currentUser.

Comment: Check all your data properly, you might have created previous data with another userId.

Comment: I probably should. It did ask me to create an composite index on Google cloud platform which I did. I wonder if this is normal as I haven't seen it anywhere else nor had it asked me to before now.

Comment: I finally figured out why it only displays the latest document created. This is because all the documents are created with the same id. What's the alternative to this? From the top of my head I'm thinking to let document id be automatically generated whilst I create a field called user_id in each document and set user_id to be currentUser() uid? Is there another hack to this?

Comment: Composite indices are very normal for firestore queries, they are for indexing your data for faster and efficient queries. For your second comment, you should allow the document Ids be automatically generated like the approach you suggested and create an "id" field so that your "where" clause for firestore query will work.

Comment: Thanks. That actually did the trick. The issue I have now is updating the data. How do I specify the where above if (isUpdating) ?

Comment: Asked in a different question here, since this is already a long thread....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222229/update-firestore-document-where-user-id-is-same-as-currentuser-uid