# Update Firestore document where user_id is same as currentUser uid

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I have the function that I am using to create or update customer.

I am able to successfully write to db. I created a field called user_id where I save the currentUser uid into so I can read only logged in user documents.

However, I am unable to update the documents because I know I'm probably not referencing the document the right way.

I get the following error:

> flutter: Error: PlatformException(Error 5, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, No
> document to update:

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my function below:

```
  Future createOrUpdateCustomer(Customer customer, bool isUpdating) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String userId = user.uid;
    print('Current logged in user uid is: $userId');

    CollectionReference customerRef =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('customers');

    if (isUpdating) {
      customer.updatedAt = Timestamp.now();    
      customer.userId = userId;    
      await customerRef.document().updateData(customer.toMap());
      print('updated customer with id: ${customer.id}');
      print('updated customer with logged in uid: ${customer.userId}');
    } else {
      customer.createdAt = Timestamp.now();

      DocumentReference documentReference = customerRef.document();

      customer.id = documentReference.documentID;
      customer.userId = userId;

      print('created customer successfully with id: ${customer.id}');

      await documentReference.setData(customer.toMap(), merge: true);
      addCustomer(customer);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update a nonexistent document. In this line,

```
await customerRef.document().updateData(customer.toMap())
```

You are creating a document reference with a randomly-generated id. You should explicitly set the `id` of the document you're updating.

Comment: oh snap! How did I miss that. Thanks for pointing that out! Silly oversight. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update the document with conditions but the reference must be the **doc id,** that you see in 2nd section of firestore interface.

Comment: Thanks Atiq! You and Riwen pointed out an obvious silly omission from my end. Appreciate it!